# Visual Studio 2017 crlf / lf

Tags: linux, windows, unix, encoding, visual-studio-2017

i have an issue with Visual Studio 2017 community.
I can't find where i can switch the end of line character from the windows crlf to unix' lf when writing code for unix when saving my files.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a following VS extension.

> [Line Endings
>   Unifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakubBielawa.LineEndingsUnifier)
>   *Unify line endings in a whole solution, a specific project, a chosen folder or a certain source file by right clicking on a solution, a
>   project or a file in the Solution Explorer.*

I had have a similar issue if manage a project by Git on Windows - VS2017 then open it on macOS - JetBrains Rider.